# What Python technologies do I need to scrape Binance Margin Data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, dynamic

I want to acquire the Borrow Limits in the Isolated Margin accounts for all the coins listed on this page https://www.binance.com/en/margin-fee. The page is dynamically generated (I've heard Selenium is the way to go with this kind of page) but also all the data is not on the page as shown. There is a Show More button below each page.
I'm only vaguely familiar with web scraping but am reasonably familiar with data science packages (I use pandas a lot). I don't want to spend time learning approaches that won't give me what I want. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Always try to search for hidden APIs in Network Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code of Isolated Margin Vip-Level API that get this data

```
maxBorrowable":"19800000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006800"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"27500000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006375"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"USDT","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"3000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00020000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"12000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"18000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00011000"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"24000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00008000"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"36000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00008000"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"36000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006000"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"36000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006000"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"60000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00004000"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"60000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003000"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"60000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003000"}],"custom":null},"symbol":"DOGEUSDT"},{"marginRatio":"10.00000000","base":{"assetName":"DOT","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"8000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00040000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"24000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00032300"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"36000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00032300"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"48000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00030600"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"60000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00030600"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"96000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00028800"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"96000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00027200"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"96000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00027200"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"96000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00025600"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"120000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00024000"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"BTC","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"3.20000000","interestRate":"0.00010000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"9.60000000","interestRate":"0.00008075"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"14.40000000","interestRate":"0.00004675"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"19.20000000","interestRate":"0.00003400"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"19.20000000","interestRate":"0.00003400"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"32.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"32.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"51.20000000","interestRate":"0.00002160"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"57.60000000","interestRate":"0.00001760"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"80.00000000","interestRate":"0.00001650"}],"custom":null},"symbol":"DOTBTC"},{"marginRatio":"5.00000000","base":{"assetName":"DOT","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"12600.00000000","interestRate":"0.00040000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"37800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00032300"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"56700.00000000","interestRate":"0.00032300"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"75600.00000000","interestRate":"0.00030600"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"94500.00000000","interestRate":"0.00030600"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"151200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00028800"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"151200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00027200"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"151200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00027200"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"151200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00025600"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"189000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00024000"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"BUSD","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"210895.00000000","interestRate":"0.00020000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"632685.00000000","interestRate":"0.00016150"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"949027.50000000","interestRate":"0.00009350"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"1265370.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006800"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"1581712.50000000","interestRate":"0.00006800"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"2530740.00000000","interestRate":"0.00004800"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"2952530.00000000","interestRate":"0.00004800"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"3374320.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003200"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"3796110.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"5272375.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002250"}],"custom":null},"symbol":"DOTBUSD"},{"marginRatio":"10.00000000","base":{"assetName":"DOT","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"14400.00000000","interestRate":"0.00040000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"43200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00032300"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"64800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00032300"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"86400.00000000","interestRate":"0.00030600"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"108000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00030600"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"172800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00028800"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"172800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00027200"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"172800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00027200"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"172800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00025600"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"216000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00024000"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"USDT","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"60000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00020000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"240000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"360000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00011000"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"480000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00008000"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"720000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00008000"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"720000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006000"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"720000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006000"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"1200000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00004000"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"1200000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003000"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"1200000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003000"}],"custom":null},"symbol":"DOTUSDT"},{"marginRatio":"3.00000000","base":{"assetName":"DREP","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"1200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00020000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"2400.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"3600.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"4800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00018000"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"6000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00018000"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"7200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00018000"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"7200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00017000"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"7200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00017000"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"7200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00016000"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"7200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00016000"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"BTC","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"0.50000000","interestRate":"0.00010000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"1.50000000","interestRate":"0.00008075"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"2.25000000","interestRate":"0.00004675"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"3.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003400"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"3.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003400"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"5.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"5.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"8.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002160"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"9.00000000","interestRate":"0.00001760"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"12.50000000","interestRate":"0.00001650"}],"custom":null},"symbol":"DREPBTC"},{"marginRatio":"3.00000000","base":{"assetName":"DREP","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"1875.00000000","interestRate":"0.00020000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"3750.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"5625.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"7500.00000000","interestRate":"0.00018000"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"9375.00000000","interestRate":"0.00018000"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"11250.00000000","interestRate":"0.00018000"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"11250.00000000","interestRate":"0.00017000"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"11250.00000000","interestRate":"0.00017000"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"11250.00000000","interestRate":"0.00016000"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"11250.00000000","interestRate":"0.00016000"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"USDT","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"4500.00000000","interestRate":"0.00020000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"18000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00019000"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"27000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00011000"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"36000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00008000"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"54000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00008000"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"54000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006000"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"54000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00006000"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"90000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00004000"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"90000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003000"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"90000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00003000"}],"custom":null},"symbol":"DREPUSDT"},{"marginRatio":"3.00000000","base":{"assetName":"DUSK","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"19800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00080000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"39600.00000000","interestRate":"0.00076000"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"59400.00000000","interestRate":"0.00076000"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"79200.00000000","interestRate":"0.00072000"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"99000.00000000","interestRate":"0.00072000"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"118800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00072000"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"118800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00068000"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"118800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00068000"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"118800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00064000"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"118800.00000000","interestRate":"0.00064000"}],"custom":null},"quote":{"assetName":"BTC","levelDetails":[{"level":"0","maxBorrowable":"0.10000000","interestRate":"0.00010000"},{"level":"1","maxBorrowable":"0.30000000","interestRate":"0.00008075"},{"level":"2","maxBorrowable":"0.45000000","interestRate":"0.00004675"},{"level":"3","maxBorrowable":"0.60000000","interestRate":"0.00003400"},{"level":"4","maxBorrowable":"0.60000000","interestRate":"0.00003400"},{"level":"5","maxBorrowable":"1.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"6","maxBorrowable":"1.00000000","interestRate":"0.00002400"},{"level":"7","maxBorrowable":"1.60000000","interestRate":"0.00002160"},{"level":"8","maxBorrowable":"1.80000000","interestRate":"0.00001760"},{"level":"9","maxBorrowable":"2.50000000","interestRate":"0.00001650"}],"cu
```

```
import requests
from fake_headers import Headers

headers = Headers(
    browser='chrome',
    os='macOS',
    headers=True
)

url = 'https://www.binance.com/bapi/margin/v1/friendly/isolated-margin/pair/vip-level'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers.generate()

main_response = s.get(url)
print(main_response.text)
```

If you use about with this URL you will get `userMaxBorrow`, `userMinBorrow` and some more:

```
[{"assetName":"BTC","assetFullName":"Bitcoin","userMaxBorrow":"60.00000000","userMinBorrow":"0.00000000","userMinRepay":"0.00000000","isBorrowable":true,"isMortgageable":true,"isAllowOpenLong":true,"isAllowOpenShort":true,"status":"NORMAL","delistedTime":null},
```

```
url = 'https://www.binance.com/bapi/margin/v1/friendly/margin/asset/all'
```

And From This URL you will get margin-ratio

```
https://www.binance.com/bapi/margin/v1/public/isolated-margin/pair/listed
```

You may find similar many APIs websites used to get data.

Without `fake_headers`

```
import requests

headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683 Safari/537.36', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3', 'DNT': '1', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1', 'Referer': 'https://google.com'}

url = 'https://www.binance.com/bapi/margin/v1/public/isolated-margin/pair/listed'
s = requests.Session()
s.headers = headers

main_response = s.get(url)
print(main_response.text)
```

For Your Answer:
You don't need any other extra technologies you just need to analyze their website request.
I have used `requests` to make requests to URLs and `fake_headers` to generate headers.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for this, I'll try it out and mark as solved when I've got it working.

Comment: I use Spyder as my IDE because I find the variable explorer very useful for working with dataframes. However recent versions of Spyder warn against using pip instead of conda to install packages. Your code requires fake_headers and the only documentation that I can find requires pip to install. I guess I could use PyCharm but if there's a way to stay with Spyder I would appreciate that. Any advice?

Comment: Then you can add headers manually, you can see the edited questions.

Comment: Actually I think I can get the data I need without creating a Session, so maybe don't need that package.

Comment: Thank you very much, you've saved me a ton of work.